# Image with lazy loading from javascript not shown in chromium/chrome

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading

I have a loader animation that is shown when an image is loaded. While the animation is done in CSS, the image is injected on a div with JS:

```
const lazyLoads = document.querySelectorAll('.lazyload')

for(let i in lazyLoads) {
  let lazyload = lazyLoads[i]
  if (!lazyload) continue

  let children = lazyload.children
  if(!children) continue

  // Inject image div
  let img = children[0]
  if(!img) continue

  let animObj = children[1]
  if(!animObj) continue

  animObj.style.animation = 'lazyloadAnim 2s linear infinite'
  let image = new Image()

  image.addEventListener('load', () => {
    setTimeout(() => { animObj.remove() }, 3000)
    img.appendChild(image)
  }, false)

  image.src = img.getAttribute('src')
  image.loading = 'lazy'
}
```

This works fine in firefox, falkon, and midori browsers. But inside chromium, I get the animation showing infinitely and the image never loads.

The solution I discovered is to remove the `image.loading = 'lazy'` code.

Why is the image getting blocked? The site has a lot of images, is there a way to get lazy loading in chrome from JavaScript?

Comment: You should probably not be using `for (let i in lastLoads)` to iterate over the `NodeList`. See [MDN's article on `NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#example), where it says "Don't use `for...in` to enumerate the items in `NodeList`s"... Use `forEach` directly on the output of `querySelectorAll` or use `for...of`, or just a plain indexed `for` loop.

Comment: Also, it's quite confusing, from just your script, what type of element `img` is. If it's a `div`, well, they don't have a `src` attribute; you should consider using `data-src` to ensure compatibility. If it's an `img` element, they don't have child elements, so you can't use `appendChild` on the element with any utility. In general, if you're going to be adding custom attributes, you should use `data-` as a prefix.